# How to get the distance between two points on the CPU image in ARCore?

Tags: android, arcore

I get the CPU image and the depth image by frame#acquireCameraImage()  and acquireRawDepthImage16Bits.

There are two points on the CPU image. For example, point A is (x1, y1), and point B is (x2, y2) in pixel. The depth of point A and point B are known.

Now I want to know the real-world distance between the two points on the CPU image. What coordinate system for those points to transform? Or what can I do for calculating the distance?